# How to get length (duration) of a source with single buffer in OpenAL?

Tags: c++, openal, fmod

I'm migrating from **FMOD** to **OpenAL** and I can't find an analogue of the **FSOUND_Sample_GetLength()** function, which returns the length of the sample in **samples** (it doesn't take frequency in consideration)... I get **OpenAL** buffer name from **alutLoadMemoryFromFileImage()**, so I can't get the waveform data this way.

Please help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to piece it together yourself using alGetBufferi():

```
ALint sizeInBytes;
ALint channels;
ALint bits;

alGetBufferi(bufferID, AL_SIZE, &sizeInBytes);
alGetBufferi(bufferID, AL_CHANNELS, &channels);
alGetBufferi(bufferID, AL_BITS, &bits);

lengthInSamples = sizeInBytes * 8 / (channels * bits);
```

And for duration in seconds:

```
ALint frequency;

alGetBufferi(bufferID, AL_FREQUENCY, &frequency);

durationInSeconds = (float)lengthInSamples / (float)frequency;
```